# how to work with non laravel packages?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

How to work with non laravel packages as i want to use  https://packagist.org/packages/kerphi/phpfreechat this packages

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: simple i downloaded the package via composer now how to initialize properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the simple [composer](http://getcomposer.org) functionality. Via commandline run:

```
composer require kerphi/phpfreechat
```

That's it the package classes should now be available within your application.

You can view the complete documentation on loading packagist dependancies on the [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#packagist) website.

**update**

You won't be able to use this package as the package requires the slim framework. You can see this on the package github page: https://github.com/kerphi/phpfreechat and the index file called during javascript usage: https://github.com/stmolivier/phpfreechat/blob/master/server/index.php

Comment: i think theres no problem autoloading on something else i have already composer install kerphi on my vendor files but how do i initialize ?

Comment: reading from the package github it has a dependancy on the slim framework; also it almost only needs a javascript library in your public directory. After that you will need to map a route to the server directory. It will not work anyway because that file requires the slim framework.

Comment: can you suggest me the best way ? :)

Comment: It won't work. Switch to the slim framework or find a different package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows then In cmd go to your project location and run this code

```
composer require kerphi/phpfreechat
```

Comment: i think theres on problem autoloading or something else i have already composer install kerphi on my vendor files but how do i initialize ?

Comment: Can you tell what error you face while doing composer update??

Comment: i am not getting error the packages is downloaded now how do i initialize the package?

Comment: See Documentation here: http://www.phpfreechat.net/   Or here:  https://github.com/kerphi/phpfreechat

Comment: i have live running chat on my local server but i am not able to integrate it on laravel 5